Appium>error: Could not start a new session
So, I have an iPhone emulator set up with Xcode, along with simple Java code in Eclipse, and I’m running an Appium server.
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;



public class QA {
    
     protected static IOSDriver driver;
       protected static WebDriverWait wait;
       protected static Actions actions;

    @Test
    public void Test() throws InterruptedException
    {
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 15");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "69383FAA-13AA-451D-80F1-03F765C414C9");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");           
        try {
            driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
             wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
             actions = new Actions(driver);
         
        }    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    
    
    
}

But I am getting the following error:
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
enter image description here
I don’t understand why. Just as additional information, I am able to run the Appium inspector without any issues. However, I am unable to run only that Java file.
I tried read same issues in different topics but my problem unique!

I solved it in next way!
I just changed Java Client in mvnrepository from last one 9.2.3 to 8.6.0 , strange it doesn’t work in versions over than 8.6.0

I solved it in next way!
I just changed Java Client in mvnrepository from last one 9.2.3 to 8.6.0 , strange it doesn’t work in versions over than 8.6.0
